# How to use .subscribe() in node-csvtojson library

Tags: node.js, json, csv, node-csv-parse

I am trying to use the csv to csv line function in node-csvtojson (documentation [here](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#convert-to-csv-lines))

```
csv({output:"line})
    .fromString(my_csv_string)
    .subscribe(csvLine => {
        console.log(csvLine)
    })
```

But I can't quite understand how I'm supposed to get each independent csv line. In debug mode, it never gets into the `subscribe` function even though my csv string is properly formed.

As a very simple use case, could someone explain to me how to get an alert box for each line ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an async operation, try using async/await to make it synchronous and enable the debugger to stop at the debugger point.

```
const convertToCSV = async (my_csv_string) => { await csv({output:"line"})
    .fromString(my_csv_string)
    .subscribe(csvLine => {
        console.log(csvLine)
    }) }
```

It should work this way.